# Unable to access environment variable in Python in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, environment-variables, virtualenv, environment

I'm trying to access environment variable which is exported in **~/.bashrc** file as below.

`export ENV=local` and did `source ~/.bashrc`. I can see the value **local** when I hit `echo $ENV` in terminal.

But in my python project (which is attached to a specific virtualenv in Pycharm) , when I try to do `os.environ['ENV']` and run the script by rigt-clicking it and Run, it is throwing **KeyError**.

I can't see the `ENV` in the output when i try to do `os.environ`.

What could be the issue? I guess the virtualenv should not cause any issue. Is it true?

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Python: 3.7.4
```

Comment: I think your method of adding environment variable to the bashrc might be wrong, because if you try `os.environ` in python it would list some variables and try any of that variable you wouldn't get error

Comment: So. where do I export environment variable so that I can access it from python?

Comment: You can better try another way to add environment variable like opening the **bashrc** file and add it directly and then try with `os.environ[..]` in python

Comment: That's what I did. Opened `bashrc` and added the variable as `export ENV=local`.

Comment: Try the solution from this link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that everytime I right click and run the script in Pycharm, it was creating a RunConfiguration which contains only one ENVIRONMENT variable which is `PYTHONBUFFERED=1`.

And I was not able to access any of the other variables. Short term resolution is that I added the environment variable `ENV=local` in that RunConfiguration.

and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`export ENV="local"`

Add this line to the last of the file **~/.bashrc** file and then restart the terminal to open python.

Now:

```
import os
os.environ['ENV']
```

It would work with expected output. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Turned out that the issue is because of Pycharm. I was able to run the script normally and receiving accessing the variable.

Comment: Okay, because I tried the same way inside my virtualenv and it worked, that's why suggested this answers again (sorry if it is redundant)

Comment: Did the problem solved or still it exists ? @SukumarRdjf

Comment: Not if I run the script directly. But in Pycharm, yes.

Comment: Can you reproduce your code, so that I may help ?

Comment: same code. I was trying to run from pycharm before. Now I ran it normally from terminal.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf No I meant entire code, because it is still working for me even in PyCharm

Comment: `import os;
ss = os.environ['ENV'];
print('ss', ss)`

Comment: Your environment variable was `ENV_NAME=local` or `ENV`?

Comment: Updated the comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200069/discussion-between-amrs-tech-and-sukumar-rdjf).